# the else part is not working in php

Tags: php

php code

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="tiger";

  /* @var $dbhandle type */
 $dbhandle = \mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    /* @var $select type */
       $select= \mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"sample")
     or mysqli_error($dbhandle);
$tnumber=(\filter_input(INPUT_POST,'tnumber'));
$capacity=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'capacity'));
$status=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'status'));
$sql1="select * from tablecheck ";
$res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql1);
$row=  mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
if($row['status'] === 'Booked')
{
echo "Please select another table";
}
else{
 $sql="update tablecheck set status='Booked' where tnumber='$tnumber' ";
/* @var $result type */
$result= \mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle));
echo "success";

  mysqli_close($dbhandle); 
}
```

Always when i enter the table number in the textbox,even if the status is not booked,it is executed as please select another table,my else part is not working.How to overcome this error..

Comment: A little tip: you can save some typing time by not adding redundant parenthesis all around the place and use it to indent code properly.

Comment: yes. i have meant if the statis is booked then perform

Comment: use **trim($row['status']) === 'Booked'**

Comment: in insert query you set status to some tnumber, but in select you dont check tnumber, you just fetch all values regardless of tnumber?

Comment: using trim my execution does changes..

Answer (score 0):

First Check if you getting the value of $row['status'] as "Booked"

```
$sql1="select * from tablecheck ";
```

In this statement you need to check the rows for status that are not booked, the select query you have returned may not return the right result always

Comment: already in the database if the status is booked,i need my if part to be executed

Answer (score -1):

change `($row['status'] === 'Booked')` for `($row['status'] == 'Booked')`

Comment: Under what circumstances is this going to matter?

Comment: no still the same,if i use ==comparison with the == operator should be avoided in netbeans

Comment: It'd matter if they're not of the same type but I highly assume that $row['status'] is of type string, just like 'Booked'.